# Why am I not able to install DeepCC package?

Tags: r

> install.packages("DeepCC")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘DeepCC’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Answer (score 1):

It's not on CRAN (`install.packages()` only installs packages found in an R package repository, CRAN by default)

From [here](https://rdrr.io/github/CityUHK-CompBio/DeepCC/):

> Install the latest version of this package by entering the following in R:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("CityUHK-CompBio/DeepCC")
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the code but I got this error:   Installing 2 packages: mxnet, isoband
Error: Failed to install 'DeepCC' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) unable to access index for repository https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/apache-mxnet/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'

Comment: does this help? https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/mxnet-for-r-3-6/3910